# Getting dates from .ics file and use inside iOS app (Xcode/Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a simple iOS sports app (Swift 3, Xcode), where the user selects their favourite team and then the app shows the dates for the next game. Later I'm planning to implement push-notifications when the game is about to start.

I found a calendar file (.ics) online with all the dates for all the games in the series, and what I would like to do is you compare the iPhones date (sysdate) with the dates in the .ics file, and if the selected team plays today it will display the start time and some other info.

An easy option would be to manually put in all the dates in the whole season to a regular database, but then I have to make changes when playoffs begin since we don't which teams will play. I think this .ics file is dynamic and will update, hence it would be convenient to use this.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has an article on the ics file format that includes a technical specification. I suggest taking a look at that.

There is also a free iOS library for parsing .ics files:

https://maniacdev.com/2014/03/open-source-ios-library-for-parsing-events-from-ics-icalendar-file-data